# Dendrogram y-axis labeling confusion

Tags: python, scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram

I have a large (106x106) correlation matrix in pandas with the following structure:

```
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
|   |         0         |        1         |        2         |        3         |        4         |        5        |        6         |        7         |        8         |         9         |
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 0 |               1.0 |   0.465539925807 |   0.736955649673 |   0.733077703346 |  -0.177380436347 | -0.268022641963 |  0.0642473239514 | -0.0136866435594 |  -0.025596700815 | -0.00385065532308 |
| 1 |    0.465539925807 |              1.0 |  -0.173472213691 |   -0.16898620433 | -0.0460674481563 | 0.0994673318696 |   0.137137216943 |   0.061999118034 |  0.0944808695878 |   0.0229095105328 |
| 2 |    0.736955649673 |  -0.173472213691 |              1.0 |   0.996627003263 |  -0.172683935315 |  -0.33319698831 | -0.0562591684255 | -0.0306820050477 | -0.0657065745626 |  -0.0457836647012 |
| 3 |    0.733077703346 |   -0.16898620433 |   0.996627003263 |              1.0 |  -0.153606414649 | -0.321562257834 | -0.0465540370732 | -0.0224318843281 | -0.0586629098513 |  -0.0417237678539 |
| 4 |   -0.177380436347 | -0.0460674481563 |  -0.172683935315 |  -0.153606414649 |              1.0 | 0.0148395123941 |   0.191615549534 |   0.289211355855 |    0.28799868259 |    0.291523969899 |
| 5 |   -0.268022641963 |  0.0994673318696 |   -0.33319698831 |  -0.321562257834 |  0.0148395123941 |             1.0 |   0.205432455075 |   0.445668299971 |   0.454982398693 |    0.427323555674 |
| 6 |   0.0642473239514 |   0.137137216943 | -0.0562591684255 | -0.0465540370732 |   0.191615549534 |  0.205432455075 |              1.0 |   0.674329392219 |   0.727261969241 |     0.67891326835 |
| 7 |  -0.0136866435594 |   0.061999118034 | -0.0306820050477 | -0.0224318843281 |   0.289211355855 |  0.445668299971 |   0.674329392219 |              1.0 |   0.980543049288 |    0.939548790275 |
| 8 |   -0.025596700815 |  0.0944808695878 | -0.0657065745626 | -0.0586629098513 |    0.28799868259 |  0.454982398693 |   0.727261969241 |   0.980543049288 |              1.0 |    0.930281915882 |
| 9 | -0.00385065532308 |  0.0229095105328 | -0.0457836647012 | -0.0417237678539 |   0.291523969899 |  0.427323555674 |    0.67891326835 |   0.939548790275 |   0.930281915882 |               1.0 |
+---+-------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

Truncated here for simplicity.

If I calculate the linkage, and later plot the dendrogram using the following code:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
Z = linkage(result_df.corr(),'average')
plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(20, 20))
axes.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=15)

dendrogram(Z=Z,labels=result_df_null_cols.columns,leaf_rotation=90.,ax=axes,color_threshold=2.);#,fig_size=[10,10]);
```

It yields a dendrogram like:
[image]

My question is surrounding the y-axis. On all examples I have seen, the Y axis is bound between 0,2 - which I have read to interpret as `(1-corr)`. In my result, the boundary is much higher. 0 being items that are highly correlated `(1-1 = 0)`, and 2 being the cutoff on lowly correlated stuff `(1 - -1 = 2)`.

I found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34175462/dendrogram-using-pandas-and-scipy) but [it does not agree with this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/82326/how-to-interpret-the-dendrogram-of-a-hierarchical-cluster-analysis) and the [referenced lecture notes here](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~michael/stanford/maeb7.pdf).

Anyway - hoping someone can clarify which source is the correct one, and help spread some knowledge on the topic.

Comment: The y-axis should be distance.  What distance metric are you using?  It looks like the default is Euclidean, in which case I suspect this is not doing what you expected.

Comment: @TheLaconic I don't disagree that the distance measure may be the issue, but is it just coincidence that this blog post https://silburt.github.io/blog/stock_correlation.html has the y-axis bound between 0,2 using the exact same methodology as I used above

Comment: I agree that it’s a puzzle, and I can’t make heads or tails of the documentation myself.