# Distance Matrix for Big Data

Tags: matlab, large-data, distance-functions, euclidean

I have been struggling to create a distance matrix for some Big Data (800,000x20). I have tried R (dist function), Matlab (pdist function), and cloud computing (to increase RAM).

Ultimately, the limitation that I come up against is the maximum array size that each program can use.

**The dist function in R returns the following error:** *Error: cannot allocate vector of size 35298.4 Gb*

This is not resolved by increasing the RAM to the largest possible size on cloud computing. Note: R is not preferred because many functions that I need to use (such as hclust) cannot process objects for more than 65536 rows.

**The pdist function in MatLab, running on an AWS cloud computer, returns the following error:** *Requested 1x252043965036 (1877.9GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference.*

I suspect that the solution is to calculate distribution matrices on subsets of the data and then fuse them together, however, I am not sure how to do this in a way that ensures that the distance between every cell is preserved. **A solution in MatLab is preferred.**

My goal is to perform cluster analysis on the data. For instance:

X= randi(5,800000,20);

Y = pdist(X);

Z = linkage(Y);

dendrogram(Z)

Comment: Roughly, you will need more than 5000 Gb memory! Another thing to mention is that hierarchical cluster analysis - the majority of its linkage methods - are only locally optimal greedy algorithm (see last point [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3277) that isn't suited for very many objects on _that_ ground, not because of memory limitation. I would recommend you to do clustering on much smaller random subsamples. Or to use another clustering method which doesn't need distance matrix. Search the site for `clustering large data`.

Comment: You can [search for threads that are tagged both "large-data" *and* "clustering"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/large-data+clustering).

Comment: What is the ultimate goal? i.e. why do you think you need to compute a distance matrix? Perhaps there is a different way of achieving your bigger objective?

Comment: Do you expect that your clusters are all equally represented in the data?

Comment: @dt688 I do not expect equal representations of the clusters

Comment: As an update: I have had some luck with kmeans and will explore other clustering algorithms. Thanks!