# How to compare two dendrograms

Tags: clustering, similarities, dendrogram

I want to find a method to compare two dendrograms. I have documents that were read by some people and they made a dendrogram that indicates which documents they think are more similar. Now I want to make dendrograms based on those documents using a few different document similarity scores starting for example from tf–idf. I want to know which similarity score gives dendrogram the most similar to what those people think. How should I compare those dendrograms? I would prefer Python libraries, the only thing I found is this tree edit distance https://github.com/timtadh/zhang-shasha

Comment: Some form of cophenetic correlation is a common method for that. See related question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/63546/3277.

Answer (score 2):

The R package dendextend implements some of the methods you are looking for.
You can implement the baker's gamma statistic.
You could find the reference to it in the dendextend paper:
https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/31/22/3718/240978

If you get to implement it in python, please mention it here for me and others in the future to know about it.