# Approximate Gower's dissimilarity measure

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, large-data, gower-similarity

I have a very large dataset with mixed-type variables. When I apply the Gower's dissimilarity measure to obtain the distance matrix, it is running out of memory. Due to the large size of the data, it's no use if I increase the memory size by memory.limit(size = xxx).

So I am wondering, is there some effective approach to approximate the gower's dissimilarity measure for large datasets? Thank you!

Comment: What is the cause of your run out of memory? Too many objects or too many variables?

Comment: I think it's due to the large sample size of the dataset. There are too many observations in the dataset. The number of variables is not big.

Comment: There is no "approximate" Gower coefficient. Just do your cluster analysis on random subsample(s) of the data. Say, of n=500 or 1000 objects. If there are clusters, they must show in a subsample of moderate size. Also, greedy methods such as hierarchical clustering are often _worse_ on huge samples than on moderate ones (see the last point [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/63549/3277)).

Answer (score 1):

As it stands it seems the main issue is that we are running out of memory because we are computing all the pair-wises distances possible. The obvious things here are:

1. use a lower [triangular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix) for storage,
2. use [`float16`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format) or `float32` instead of the native [`float64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format),
3. impose sparsity such that we only calculate distances from the $k$-nearest neighbours found using a [ball tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_tree).

Comment: Oh, that's a smart way to store the lower triangular matrix. But I need to compute silhouette score using the distance matrix. Is it okay to use a lower triangular one instead? Thanks!

Comment: Of course, it is as the distance matrix is symmetric by definition in the case of Gower's distance. (If it wasn't we would need both the upper and lower triangular parts of it.)

Comment: I am using fpc::cluster.stats(dis_mat, cluster) to get the silhouette scores. If dis_mat is lower triangular matrix, what about the cluster? I just tried this but it failed. The cluster is taken from the whole dataset for each obs.

Comment: Apologies, I don't know how `fpc::cluster.stats` does its internal calculations. As mentioned all pair-wise distances can be defined fully in a triangular matrix if the original distance matrix is symmetric. Maybe you need to reimplement some of `fpc::cluster.stats` steps.